# elasticsearch clustering issue

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using two ES nodes (ES version 1.0.1) in cluster and I need clarification for following:

When I start application and it connects to both nodes and I can see requests served by both nodes but when I stop one of server it throws exception and other node still works but 50% of requests still get exception and whole traffic is not diverted to running node.

I have following configuration for cluster:
1st Node:

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

node.data: true

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["product-elasticsearch-1","product-elasticsearch-2"]

node.master: true

couchbase.maxConcurrentRequests: 1024

2nd Node
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

node.data: true

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["product-elasticsearch","product-elasticsearch-2"]

node.master: false

couchbase.maxConcurrentRequests: 1024
```

Following is code for transport client:

```
settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", clusterName)
        .put("es.http.timeout",timeout)
        .put("client.transport.ping_timeout",pingTimeout)
        .put("es.http.retries",retries)
        .build();

for (String host : hostList) {
    transportAddressList.add(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host,port));
}
Collections.shuffle(transportAddressList);

// Using Transport Client
trasportClient = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddresses(transportAddressList.toArray(addressArray));
```

Could someone please let me know when I stop one ES process why all requests are not served by running node?

Answer (score 0):

Which one are you bringing down? The second node has the following property:
node.master: false

This could result in problems if only that node is running.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply. So another observation is that if we run in master-master mode where node.master : true for both ES nodes it works meaning if one of node goes down then other will work. But if we run two ES nodes in master-slave mode where for slave node.master is false and master is down then it will not work. Is there any way we can make master-slave model working when master is down?

Comment: To my opinion there is no method to do this. There is no clear master-slave modus in elasticsearch. There are child, data and master roles in which a child node indicates it has neither the master nor the data role.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. So another observation/solution is that if we run in master-master mode where node.master : true for both ES nodes it works meaning if one of node goes down then other will work. But if we run two ES nodes in master-slave mode where for slave node.master is false and master is down then slave will not work without master. Is there any way we can make master-slave model working with only slave when master is down?